# Display text in table with a fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have a list of users I wish to display in a table format. The problem I have is that I only have 30px of width available, so I need to break any names which span more than this onto a new line.

HTML

```
<table>
       <tr>
          <td>User ID</td>
          <td style="width:40px;">User's Full Name</td>
       </tr>
       @foreach(var user in @Model)
       {
          <tr>
             <td>@user.Id</td>
             <td style="width:40px;">@user.Name</td>
          </tr>
       }
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{
    width:40px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Any names longer just force the width to increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this property

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Your td's markup

```
<td style="width:40px;word-wrap:break-word;">@user.Name</td>
```